# SELECT dropdownlist value from database repeated

Tags: php, mysql, database, select

I am using PHP to change the  value of a dropdownlist menu in my database.
The status I am using are:  New - progress - Wait - Done - Close
Suppose that all the new entry are with status "NEW"

When I change the value I can still see a double option.

Here my code:

```
<td>
    <select class='form-control col-sm-10' id='status' name='status'>
        <option value=" . $row['status'] . " >" . $row['status'] . "</option>
        <option value='new'>New</option>
        <option value='progress'>Progress</option>
        <option  value='wait'>Wait</option>
        <option value='done'>Done</option>
        <option value='close'>Close</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

And a picture: [image]

--------------------- FULL CODE --------------

```
<?php

include("../includes/connection.php");

if ($link->connect_errno > 0) {
    die('Unable to connect to database [' . $link->connect_error . ']');
}

if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $results = $link->query("UPDATE job SET status='$_POST[status]', priority='$_POST[priority]' WHERE id='$_POST[hidden]'");
    $results = $link->query("UPDATE customer SET status='$_POST[status]' WHERE id='$_POST[hidden]'");
}

$sql = "SELECT * from job";
if (!$result = $link->query($sql)) {
    die('There was an error running the query [' . $link->error . ']');
}
echo "
<table class='table'>
    <thead>
        <tr>";
/* Get field information for all columns */
while ($finfo = $result->fetch_field()) {
    echo "
        <th>" . $finfo->name . "</th>";
}
echo "
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>";


while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

      $job_id = $row['id'];
    echo "<form action='' method=post>";

    echo "<tr class='info'>

                <input type=hidden name=hidden value=" . $row['id'] . ">
                <td>" . $row['id'] . "</td> 
                <td>" . $row['device'] . "</td>
                  <td>" . $row['model'] . "</td> 
                <td>" . $row['problem'] . "</td>

                <td><select class='form-control col-sm-10' id='status' name='status'>
                                  <option value=" . $row['status'] . " >" . $row['status'] . "</option>
                  <option value='new'  >New</option>
                  <option value='progress'>Progress</option>
                  <option  value='wait'>Wait</option>
                  <option value='done'>Done</option>
                  <option value='close'>Close</option>
                       </select></td>

                <td><select class='form-control col-sm-10' id='priority' name='priority'>
                        <option value=" . $row['priority'] . "  >" . $row['priority'] . "</option>
                        <option value='high'>High</option>
                        <option value='medium'>Medium</option>
                        <option  value='low'>Low</option>
                       </select></td>

                <td> <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' name='update'>Update</button></td>

                <td> <a class='btn btn-primary btn-sm'  data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'   name='[$job_id]' value='[$job_id]'  >  Info</a></td>


            </tr>";
    echo "</form>";
}
echo "
    </tbody>

</table>";

?>
```

Comment: Going to need to see a lot more code to offer any help - but presumably  `$row['status']` contains the selected option

Comment: $row['status'] contains the current status. Status can change thats why I put it as a first option, in the way that everytime you can see in which status you are, but still able to change it throught a button. Which other code do you need?

Comment: I am using $row['status'] to be able to change the status with another one of the dropdownlist. The problem is that I can choose in the dropdownmenu also the status that is already selected and thats not correct. I should diplay only all the other status which are not currently selected.

Comment: both the upvoted questions do exactly that

Comment: I see, since I have my code already into a PHP tags, I am trying to figure out why I get a Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''

Comment: Hm, i think i can guess whats happening, but could you edit your question to show more code - eg the bit where you echo the string currently shown

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96881/discussion-between-gigi-and-steve).

Comment: Ok, i wrote an answer - the techique is the same as in the two other answers, only the syntax is changed to use ternary ifs as you cant use a regular control structure in string concatenation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<td>
    <select class='form-control col-sm-10' id='status' name='status'>
        <option value='new' <?if($row['status']=='new'){echo "selected";}?>>New</option>
        <option value='progress' <?if($row['status']=='progress'){echo "selected";}?>>Progress</option>
        <option value='wait' <?if($row['status']=='wait'){echo "selected";}?>>Wait</option>
        <option value='done' <?if($row['status']=='done'){echo "selected";}?>>Done</option>
        <option value='close' <?if($row['status']=='close'){echo "selected";}?>>Close</option>
    </select>
</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

check PHP variable with option value and if it is matched then add atttribute `selected='selected'` for that.

```
<option value='new' <?php if($row['status'] == 'new') { echo "selected='selected'" ; } ?> >New</option>
<option value='progress' <?php if($row['status'] == 'progress') { echo "selected='selected'" ; } ?>>Progress</option>
<option  value='wait' <?php if($row['status'] == 'wait') { echo "selected='selected'" ; } ?> >Wait</option>
<option value='done' <?php if($row['status'] == 'done') { echo "selected='selected'" ; } ?>>Done</option>
<option value='close' <?php if($row['status'] == 'close') { echo "selected='selected'" ; } ?> >Close</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you can check the value of `$row['status']` and selectivly add the selected attribute to the correct option:

```
"<td>
    <select class='form-control col-sm-10' id='status' name='status'>
        <option value='new' ". ($row['status'] == 'new'? 'selected ': '') .">New</option>
        <option value='progress' ". ($row['status'] == 'progress'? 'selected ': '') .">Progress</option>
        <option  value='wait' ". ($row['status'] == 'wait'? 'selected ': '') .">Wait</option>
        <option value='done' ". ($row['status'] == 'done'? 'selected ': '') .">Done</option>
        <option value='close' ". ($row['status'] == 'close'? 'selected ': '') .">Close</option>
    </select>
</td>"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to select specific option, you need to set [selected attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp) to option tag:

```
<option value='new' <?if($row['status']=='new'){echo "selected";}?>>New</option>
```

Comment: I need to select the otion which is stored in the database and I do it with `<option value=" . $row['status'] . " >" . $row['status'] . "</option>`. The problem is that I can choose in the dropdownmenu also the voice that is already selected.